# python: swapping giving error index error out of range

Tags: python-2.7

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,'a','b','c']
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]=='a':
        temp=a[i+1]
        a[i+1]=a[i]
        a[i]=temp
```

this is my school project.
This particular block of code is giving me error of index out of range in python?
i am really not able to understand why's that i am trying to swap 'a' and 'b' ?
help please!

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is from 0 to len(a), then `i+1` is out of bounds for indexing in a.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,'a','b','c']
print("list length: %d" % len(a))
for i in range(len(a)):
if a[i]=='a':
    print("swap a[%d] and a[%d]: " % (i+1, i))
    temp=a[i+1]
    a[i+1]=a[i]
    a[i]=temp 
    print(a)
```

and the out:

```
list length: 9
swap a[7] and a[6]: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'b', 'a', 'c']
swap a[8] and a[7]: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'b', 'c', 'a']
swap a[9] and a[8]: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 6, in <module>
    temp=a[i+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: yup i figured it out immedately after posting it in here...i am so sorry for asking such a silly question

Comment: i had just added "break " statement to come out of the for loop.thanks!!

Comment: @user3091069 :), you can accpet the answer.